# Axis label positioning in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Can someone please help me explain why label positioning in the following code does not work? It is not clear what I am doing wrong. I also tried `axis description cs`. That does not change the label position either.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4in,
        height=4in,
        xlabel={Quantity},
        % the following x label positioning does not work.
        every axis x label/.style=
            {at={(ticklabel cs: 0.5)}, anchor=north},
        ylabel={Price},
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ytick={0,10,...,90},
        xtick={0,10,...,90},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        xlabel shift = -1in,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,90) (90,0)};
        \addplot[color=red,domain=0:40]{2*x} node [pos=1,above]{MC};

        % why is this node not visible.
        \node at (axis description cs:0.5,-0.02) {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`axis x line` redefines the label style, move your definition to after that. Note that you seem to need specify a y-coordinate of zero as well, i.e. `(ticklabel cs:0.5,0)`.

Read section 4.9.1 *Placement of axis descriptions* in the `pgfplots` manual for more discussion about the `ticklabel` coordinate system(s).

As for the invisible node, everything outside the axis limits is by default clipped away. If you set `clip mode=individual`, plots will be clipped, but `\node`s and similar will not be clipped.

Finally, `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, so you don't actually have to load the latter explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=4in,
        height=4in,
        xlabel={Quantity},
        ylabel={Price},
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        % the following x label positioning does work here.
        every axis x label/.style=
            {at={(ticklabel cs: 0.5,0)}, anchor=north},
        ytick={0,10,...,90},
        xtick={0,10,...,90},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=100,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=100,
        xlabel shift = -1in,
        clip mode=individual
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,90) (90,0)};
        \addplot[color=red,domain=0:40]{2*x} node [pos=1,above]{MC};

        % why is this node not visible.
        \node at (axis description cs:0.5,-0.02) {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works great! Can you please explain why the following places the y-label at the bottom of the y-axis and not in the middle of the y-axis:
`every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs: 0,0.5)}}`. Thank you.

Comment: @Curious2learn The `ticklabel` coordinate systems are aligned with the axes, so an x-value of zero is always at the start of the axis, and 1 at the end. The `y` coordinate is a shift perpendicular to the axis line, with the positive direction away from the axis.