# pgfplots: shifting scope via named coordinate

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following MWE: I find it amusing that the second `tikzpicture` cannot compile without the first, even though the second value for `(A)` is the one being used. Can anyone explaing this?

In my real example I have a a function plot from which I store some coordinates. Later on I need to add some extra drawings at these named points.
Are there any way of doing this other than delaying the `scope` I use to place things until after `\end{axis}`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % remove this and the second tikzpicture does not compile
   \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmax=3,xmin=0,ymax=3,ymin=0
    ]
     \draw (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs:3,3)
     coordinate [pos=0.4] (A)
     ;
     \fill (A) circle (2pt);

     % more this scope until after \end{axis} and we do not need
     % to have (A) defined in another image
     \begin{scope}[
       shift={(A)},
       ]
       \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
     \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the scope inside `\pgfplotsextra{...}`

Comment: @percusse That worked, never heard of that one, given an answer. BTW: do you know if the pgfplots have something similar to `\tikzstyle` such that common options to `axis` can be collected into one style?

Comment: The axis environment automatically delays some things to run after \end{axis}. but not others.

Comment: Yes `\pgfplotstyle{every axis={...}}` and related ones are in the manual. Note that it's not `every axis/.style` but only the key. More is given in the manual for post processing etc.

Comment: You can use `style` with `pgfplotsset`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139084/38080 --- @percusse, I'd like to see an answer on this, I  never heard about `\pgfplotsextra{}` too....

Comment: pgfplotsstyle is stupid sorry I meant `pgfplotsset`

Comment: @percusse do you know if one can use the delaying stuff to get outside the clipping. At least in my case I often want to use the clipping to limit the plot, but other stuff that I add can go beyond the borders.

Comment: `clip mode=individual` ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301585/axis-label-positioning-in-pgfplots

Comment: @Rmano, that worked, thanks. Too many options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `pgfplots` has a two phase workflow, first collect and queue and second do the visualization non plotting commands need to be collected in the right order if depends on the previous commands. Otherwise they can be prematurely executed as happened here.

Inspired by `\pgfextra` (I think), there is a similar command in `pgfplots` which is `\pgfplotsextra` that actually helps to queue non`pgfplots` commands to the existing ones. Though I would expect this to work automatically because recent versions of `pgfplots` automatically recognizes the raw TikZ commands somehow didn't go through. Hence we do it manually by putting the scope inside the `\pgfplotsextra`.